# Emacs: Turn off indentation when doing a paragraph fill in LaTeX mode

Tags: emacs

When I am using emacs to edit a latex document the paragraph fill (Esc-q) does not do what I want. For example, something like:

```
The component \vn{%vec} is not similar to
```

When I use fill I get:

```
The component \vn{%vec} is not
                  % similar to
```

That is, emacs is taking "%" to be a comment character and filling the paragraph accordingly. However, "\vn" is a macro of mine that sets text in texttt mode and here "%" is simply a regular printable character so the paragraph fill has done things incorrectly.

So what I want is for paragraph fill to be the same it is as in text-mode. That is, no indentation and no adding extra characters. But I don't want to have to toggle between text-mode and latex-mode every time I want to paragraph fill. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for the help. -- David

PS: Yes, I do know that if there are real comments at the end of lines then the test-mode fill will not do things correctly. But I never put comments at the end of lines so this will never bother me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I put this in my init.el file:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook        '(lambda() (setq comment-start nil)))
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook          '(lambda() (setq comment-start nil)))

(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook        '(lambda() (setq fill-indent-according-to-mode nil)))
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook          '(lambda() (setq fill-indent-according-to-mode nil)))
```

I love emacs but the documentation (or lack thereof) can sometimes drive me crazy... :).

Comment: You've solved one symptom of a bug by breaking other features.  Please consider using `report-emacs-bug` to file an issue.

Comment: Note that `setq` can set multiple variables at once.

Comment: To event_jr: Is this really a bug? There is no way emacs can tell that % is a comment character or not in this situation. Especially since "\vn" is defined in another file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
(setq comment-start nil)
```

to handle this specific case.

Comment: This helps but I still get some funny indentation. For example:

    Line 1...
    Line 2...
    Line 3...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to fix is a symptom of the real problem -- `latex-mode` is
naively marking code after "%" as comment.

Does installing [auctex-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) fix your problem?