# Prevent Auctex indentation with (fill-paragraph)

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, indentation, auctex

I prefer not to use indentation in my LaTeX documents because it makes cooperating with users of other editors more difficult.  This is typically pretty easy to achieve, except that Auctex likes to automatically indent whenever I use `(fill-paragraph)`.

For example, if I have something like:

```
\begin{abstract}
Some series of sentences here.
\end{abstract}
```

When I run `(fill-paragraph)` I get something like

```
\begin{abstract}
  Some series of
  sentences here.
\end{abstract}
```

I don't want the filled text to be indented.

Note that I *don't* want to disable this functionality Emacs-wide, because I like being able to fill indented comments and such in other modes.  I just don't want it to happen in Auctex.

How can I achieve this?

I've already seen this question [1], but it only has a partial solution for latex-mode, not Auctex.

[1] [Emacs: Turn off indentation when doing a paragraph fill in LaTeX mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743708/emacs-turn-off-indentation-when-doing-a-paragraph-fill-in-latex-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the customization variables `LaTeX-indent-level` and `LaTeX-item-indent` to 0 you'll get rid of most or all of AucTex's indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (kill-local-variable 'line-indent-function)))
```

so as to disable LaTeX's indentation algorithm.